# Postman Tests: There was an error in evaluating the test script

Tags: testing, postman, postman-testcase

**I am testing the application** and face this error, **I want to include this error in my script** but I don't know-how.

This error **happens** because I **write the wrong variable name** on the **body**, and is also part of the **process to test**.

I want to do something like that:

```
pm.test("There was an error in evaluating the test script", 
    function(){
    pm.expect(??.??).to.eql("There was an error in evaluating the test 
    script:  JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <pre class="cake-error"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="document.getElem ^");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
const resBody = pm.response.text();

pm.test("There was an error in evaluating the test script", function(){ 
    pm.expect(resBody).to.include("There was an error in evaluating the test script: JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"document.getElem ^");
});
```